# Segmentation Fault in p_thread

Tags: c, multithreading, dynamic, segmentation-fault

**Issue:**

I created a linked list of Child thread TIDS and want to wait on all the child tids to finish execution before i continue my main thread. Basically I have directory traversal (a directory is specified by the members of a given struct). Every time I see a directory or file I create a new thread and put its threadID into the linked list. However when I traverse the linked list and call `pthread_join` I get a segmentation fault (core dumped) - I cannot understand why. I Can never wait on a child thread in my While loop at the bottom. Do I have to explicitly exit the child treads when I am done with them?

[Here is the output of my Compilation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/38k7D.png)

Program:

```
void *handy(void *arguments)
{   
    handarg *thestruct=(handarg*)arguments; 

    DIR *dp=opendir(thestruct->directory);  
    DIR *outExist=opendir(thestruct->outputdirectory);

    if(outExist==NULL)
    {
        if((thestruct->outputdirectory = ""))
        {
            ;   
        }
        else
        {
            printf("The outputdirectory doesnt exist, program terminated\n");
            exit(1);
        }
    }

    struct dirent *entry;  // has two important members (d-type)-tells me if its a directory (d-name) tells me current file name
    if(dp==NULL)
    {
        printf("directory doesnt exist: %s\n", thestruct->directory);
        exit(1);
    }
    NODE *head=(NODE*)malloc(sizeof(NODE)); //linked list
    NODE *ptr=(NODE*)malloc(sizeof(NODE));//node POINTER
    head=NULL;
    int count;

    while((entry=readdir(dp))!=NULL)
    {
        if(strcmp(entry->d_name,"..")==0||strcmp(entry->d_name,".")==0)
        {
           continue;
        }
        if((entry->d_type==DT_DIR))
        {
            unsigned int const sz1 = strlen(thestruct->directory);
            unsigned int const sz2 = strlen(entry->d_name);

            char *dnewname=(char *)malloc((sz1+sz2+2)*sizeof(char));

            memcpy(dnewname,thestruct->directory,sz1);
            memcpy(dnewname+sz1,"/",sizeof(char));
            memcpy(dnewname+sz1+1,entry->d_name,sz2);
            dnewname[strlen(dnewname)]='\0';
            pthread_t tid;
            handarg *current=(handarg*)malloc(sizeof(handarg));//malloc
            current->directory=dnewname;
            current->outputdirectory=thestruct->outputdirectory;
            current->column=thestruct->column;
            pthread_create(&tid,NULL,&handy,current);
            printf("The Filepath is: %s, The Parent TID = %ld, THE peer TID = %ld\n",dnewname, pthread_self(), tid);
            NODE *newNode=(NODE*)malloc(sizeof(NODE));
            if(head==NULL)
            {
                head=newNode;
                ptr=newNode;
                newNode->peerTid=tid;
                newNode->next=NULL;
                //printf("THE TID I PUT INTO THIS NODE IS %ld\n",ptr->peerTid);
            }
            else
            {
                ptr=head;
                while(ptr->next!=NULL)
                {
                ptr=ptr->next;  
                }
                ptr->next=newNode;
                newNode->peerTid=tid;
                newNode->next=NULL;

                //printf("THE TID I PUT INTO THIS NODE IS %ld\n",ptr->peerTid);

            }
            //pthread_join(tid,NULL);
            // dont want to do this this does not make sense you 
            // create all your child threads make sure they are running KEEP Track of them (know their tid ) //create an array of tids or linked list  then for loop 
            //for loop tids  and wait on all of them 
            // then join all the threads (wait)
            //say y ou have ann array of 5 tids for loop the array and call wait on each of tids  for loop only exit if last tid is waiting on 
        }

        if((entry->d_type==DT_REG))
        {
            char *filename = entry->d_name;
            int len = strlen(filename);
            const char *last_four = &filename[len-4]; //need to account for if filename is less than 4 characters   
            if(strcmp(last_four,".csv")==0)
            {   
                //here is where i call handle file and merge sort
                char *dnewname = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*(strlen(thestruct->directory)+strlen(entry->d_name)+2));
                char *slash = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char));
                strcpy(dnewname, thestruct->directory);
                strcpy(slash, "/");
                strcat(dnewname, slash);
                strcat(dnewname, entry->d_name);
                dnewname[strlen(dnewname)]='\0';

                pthread_t tid;
                handarg *current=(handarg*)malloc(sizeof(handarg));
                current->directory=dnewname;
                current->outputdirectory=thestruct->outputdirectory;
                current->column=thestruct->column;
                pthread_create(&tid,NULL,&handleFile,current);

                printf("The Filepath is: %s, The Parent TID = %ld, THE peer TID = %ld\n",dnewname, pthread_self(), tid);
                NODE *newNode=(NODE*)malloc(sizeof(NODE));
                if(head==NULL)
                {
                    head=newNode;
                    ptr=newNode;
                    newNode->peerTid=tid;
                    newNode->next=NULL;
                    //printf("THE TID I PUT INTO THIS NODE IS %ld\n",ptr->peerTid);
                }
                else
                {
                    ptr=head;
                    while(ptr->next!=NULL)
                    {
                        ptr=ptr->next;  
                    }
                    ptr->next=newNode;
                    newNode->peerTid=tid;
                    newNode->next=NULL;

                    //printf("THE TID I PUT INTO THIS NODE IS %ld\n",ptr->peerTid);
                }
            }               
        }
    }

    ptr=head;
    printf("\nthese are the items from the linkedlist\n\n");
    while (ptr!=NULL)
    {
        printf("%ld\n",ptr->peerTid);
        ptr=ptr->next;
    }
        printf("\n");
    ptr=head;
    while (ptr!=NULL)
    {
        printf("THE PEER THREAD I AM WAITING ON IS %ld --------I AM THE THREAD %ld\n",ptr->peerTid,pthread_self());
        pthread_join(ptr->peerTid,NULL);
        ptr=ptr->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
    //return NULL;
}
```

Comment: Why are you asking the exact same question twice?

Comment: ..having not fixed any of the issues raised last time:(

Comment: At least you got rid of the accidentally-left-in rude comment.